# webView cintent width

Tags: javascript, android, webview

How to detect content width in webView?
This method return not realy width:

```
setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            injectJavascript();
            loadUrl("javascript:alert(document.body.offsetWidth)");
        }
    });
```